# Is it possible to bind the sorting of a column to a different property than its display property with Angular UI Grid?

Tags: angularjs, sorting, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I was just wondering if anyone knew of a way to sort a column in the same order as another column using Angular UI Grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you mean that if (for example) you have "First Name" and "Last Name" columns which display first name and last name respectively, you want to click sort on "Last Name" and this actually sorts the table in order of "First Name"?

If so, you can accomplish this using a cell template.

Assume you have the following table:

[image]

and when you sort the "Last Name" column it will actually sort the table in order of the data in the "First Name" column.

Assuming the following data:

```
$scope.gridOptions.data = [{
    "firstName": "David",
    "lastName": "Carney",
}, {
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "lastName": "Wise",
}, {
    "firstName": "Peter",
    "lastName": "Thompson",
}];
```

Define your `columnDefs` as follows:

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [{
    name: 'firstName',
    field: 'firstName'
}, {
    name: 'lastName',
    field: 'firstName',
    cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{row.entity.lastName}}</div>'
}];
```

The column definition for the second column names the column "Last Name" and the cell template ensures the `lastName` attribute is displayed in the cell, however as the column's `field` is bound to `firstName` it means when the column is sorted it is sorted on `firstName`.

An example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dsg0mzge/4/). Sort the second column (Last Name) and the rows will actually be sorted in order of the first column (First Name).

Comment: In this case, You have to even overwrite the editable cell template for the "lastName" column definition

Answer (score 1):

Grid passes even rows as arguments along with field values to the sort function. It invokes the sort function some thing like below :

```
  sortFn(propA, propB, rowA, rowB, direction);
```

You can use this extra info to sort the data appropriately.

You can specify the sortFunc by sortingAlgorithm property for the colDef.

This happens from the ui-grid version 3.0.7